# VBA dim ws as worksheets (not worksheet)

Tags: vba, excel

OK so, I know I can do this:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
Set ws = thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1")
```

and then do my fancy stuff with the `ws` worksheet object

I also know I can `Dim wss as worksheets` and that using `worksheets("Sheet1")` returns the worksheet object. So why doesn't the following work?

```
Dim wss as worksheets
Dim ws as worksheet
Set wss = thisworkbook.worksheets
Set ws = wss("Sheet1")
```

I've also tried:

```
Dim wss as worksheets
Dim ws as worksheet
Set ws = thisworkbook.wss("Sheet1")
```

but the latter just looks like I'm trying to rename/shorten "worksheets" which seems totally wrong. I'm trying to get the worksheets of a workbook in to one worksheets object called wss. This is more about trying to understand the heirachy than anything but for functional purposes I'm trying to get wss to encompass all worksheets from workbook x so I could just do `ws = wss(1)` instead of saying `set ws = wb.worksheets(1)`

Is that even possible or am I misunderstanding the worksheets/ worksheet relationship?

Comment: It's generally easiest to find answers to questions like this by [using the Object Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251681.aspx) and looking at the method or property definitions.

Comment: I had a look at the members for Sheets and Worksheets and they're both the same. The help file says `Worksheets` returns the worksheets collection, which I thought'd be fine since I'm not interested in charts. I just wanted to harness the workbook.worksheets collection with a worksheets object. I think I'm missing something simple so thought I'd see what this forum has on offer! I see the most creative code and/or simple explanations on here (compared to official documentation).

Comment: The documentation is misleading.  If you look at the `Sheets` and `Worksheets` *properties* you'll see that they both return a `Sheets` object.

Comment: OK that's where the confusion was. I didn't quite get why `Worksheets` would return a `Sheets` collection instead of just a `Worksheets` collection. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It's a `Sheets` collection of `Worksheets` only. I think I've had enough of VBA for today :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you must declare `wss` as a [Sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193217.aspx) object

```
Dim wss As Sheets
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Set ws = wss("Sheet1")
```

this is because [Worksheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835542(v=office.15).aspx) property of `Workbook` object returns a `Sheets` collection, i.e. a collection that contains both `Worksheets` and `Charts` object of the workbook

Should you need a collection of your `Workbook` `Worksheets` only (not `Charts`) to be called like ws = wss(1) or the likes then you could adopt the following workaround with `Collection` object

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim wss As Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wss = GetWorkSheets
    Set ws = wss("Sheet1")
    Set ws = wss(1)
End Sub

Function GetWorkSheets() As Collection
    Dim wss As New Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        wss.add ws, ws.Name
    Next ws
    Set GetWorkSheets = wss
End Function
```

Comment: OK that gets me closer to understanding. It is still a little confusing to me overall, so one can `Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Sheets` to return a `Sheets` collection but if you do `Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` that also returns a `Sheets` collection?

Comment: No, that would be an invalid assignment since as per Excel Object model  `Worksheets` property of `Workbook` object returns a `Sheets` collection. Thus `Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` results in a `type mismatch error`

Comment: Awesome and thank you for the edit update with the function. You guys rock.

Comment: You don't need a special function to get a collection of worksheets. `Dim wss As Sheets` and `Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` returns a Sheets collection object that only contains the worksheets (and not charts or macro sheets). And you can use `Debug.Print wss(1).Name` for example.

Comment: @DickKusleika, yes you're right and jamheadart already got that (see its last comment). I'll leave `GetWorkSheets` function as an example of how to build and use a customized worksheets collection